# How to change figure caption label

Tags: floats, formatting, ieeetran

How can i change my figure caption from Fig. 1 to Figure 1
I am using IEEEtran template. My code looks like below

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2.1in,width=3.3in]{FPR_PpuCmpr}
\caption{False Positive Rate (FPR) Vs $P_{pu}$ (Majority Rule) }
\label{figureFPR_PpuCmpr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal, the journal sets these things, if you are not then don't use IEEEtran, use a more generic class designed for customisation (but `\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
```

should work.